# Why can't I create quarto documents in RStudio anymore?

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto

I have been using RStudio to generate quarto documents, but recently the ability to create quarto docs just disappeared from my RStudio UI. I can create RMarkdown docs and regular markdown, but not quarto. I didn't think too much of it until my existing quarto docs lost the ability to render into anything other than html.

I can't seem to find anything online for anyone who has had this issue. Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm using the latest versions of both R (4.3.1) and RStudio (2023.09.01) and am on Windows 11.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried uninstalling then reinstalling quarto. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both R and RStudio. I've tried deleting the "local" and "roaming" AppData folders for RStudio (where the preferences are set). I've tried every combination, but I still can't just click on "new file" and create a quarto doc. All of my settings were reset to default (I can tell because my custom skins are reset), but I still can't create quarto docs.

Comment: I understand you are asking to do this from RStudio. However, as a short term workaround have you tried rendering from the Terminal inside RStudio or on the windows command line?

Comment: I have tried that, but it gives me the "this program is blocked by group policy" error (IT has my work computer kind of locked down).